# Wi-Fi mesh devices limits

Tags: wireless-networking

I just set up a WiFi mesh (Tenda MW6).

The specs says up to 30 devices for every node. I have a lot of smart home devices, for now under 30 but what will happens if I have more than 30 devices on a single node? I can accept a slower network but I don't want devices offline.

Comment: For a router, there is a setting to set a fixed maximum number of devices. You can wait and see if that's an issue... but you can always add another node for 30 more devices. (~US$80 at Amazon, for example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.